# facebook oauth login error , using php sdk in CodeIgniter 2.2

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, oauth

## I tried facebook oauth login, using php sdk. but it's not going very well.

I'm web engineer in japan. I have a trouble.
I developing a web application. The application has to facebook oauth attestation.

### structure

- linux server * 3 on AWS
- PHP 5.3
- MySQL 5.5
- CodeIgniter 2.2
- CodeIgniter DB Session (MySQL)
- Facebook SDK for PHP

I tried supplement **HTTPS** after developed the Application.
The Application can use facebook API until then.

Subsequently, The Application can't access facebook api at some time :(

### this code is callback url after try login,  maybe error code.

`?code=AQBM-p7GxUdlI5osh9O6bcthukWn96kv_baPnNLdzNIIa1Q9kcxHwNv0MiBhgkUht0U3BCd6UZKn-S3odHbAVZHW8JEwkf31FXuKILLVUemmlzlF4HpJ8ysZVpjqKgjrjXR-WaJ_ITW8c0hdzr_8D3QbPCiAYePL_dfuQ4uAhgQGaw6U7G8xOWNiiPOa2_xKYFH2zC3Ce6Pf_wtKdrG5Rjk2o6Tk4Eofhc4EdngZ9K5I4hMqHC3X-2NYntFz8rPBf0xbOCX_oYJZXY6co1dNgdhIeaXEsrGQSzcNo6NQChBCBXFjB17zLtA27SyeuLT4z9w&state=30dcf57216e63b17387e9d6842cbb108#_=_`

Please tell me this topic solucion.
I'dont know cause. FB API specifications, FB App Setting, CodeIgniter, AWS... ?

Haw to use facebook oauth using https.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out Solve the Issue [phpwdn.com](http://www.phpwdn.com/oauth-login-system-facebookgooglemicrosoft-google/)

this is will return the as the php array. you can this is as Further, Check demo first [Click to Visit demo](http://www.phpwdn.com/Oauth)

Answer (score 0):

In file "FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php"

replace

```
if (isset($response['access_token'])) {
    return new FacebookSession($response['access_token']);
```

by

```
if (isset($response->access_token)) {
    return new FacebookSession($response->access_token);
```